# how can you deselect the other item once you have selected an item from the collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview, uiimageview

In Swift.
When reselecting the first item it works very well (it is deselected) but I have the problem that
when using "collection.allowsMultipleSelection = true" when selecting the second or third item it paints everything for me (which I don't want). Any solution to be able to deselect the previous item and when I select the new item that changes the deselected item (previous)? In swift.

Comment: Why do you want to enable `allowsMultipleSelection` then?

Comment: To select the element that I touched but the problem is that I touch another element and the previous element is the same (without any change)

Comment: This is the behavior of `allowsMultipleSelection`. Disable it so it would deselect the previous item.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your goal is:

- allow **only a single cell** to be selected at a time
- also allow tapping a selected cell to de-select it

If so, you can do it a couple different ways.

One - set the collection view `.allowsMultipleSelection = false` and implement `shouldSelectItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // get array of already selected index paths
    if let a = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        // if that array contains indexPath, that means
        //  it is already selected, so
        if a.contains(indexPath) {
            // deselect it
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            return false
        }
    }
    // no indexPaths (cells) were selected, so return true
    return true
}
```

Two - set `.allowsMultipleSelection = true` and implement `didSelectItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // get array of already selected index paths
    if let a = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        // for each path in selected index paths
        a.forEach { pth in
            // if it is NOT equal to the tapped cell
            if pth != indexPath {
                // deselect it
                collectionView.deselectItem(at: pth, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Magnificent. You saved me friend. Your solution is very good. Thank you @donmag